# Alternative way to use lot of 'if' statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Hello i am Novice at Python and i don't really know how to minimalize my own code that uses too much 'if' statement

```
    for c in input():
        if c in "a" or "A":
            print("1")
        if c in "b" or "B":
            print("2")
        if c in "c" or "C":
            print("3")
        if c in "d" or "D":
            print("4")
        if c in "e" or "E":
            print("5")
        if c in "f" or "F":
            print("6")
        if c in "g" or "G":
            print("7")
        if c in "h" or "H":
            print("8")
        if c in "i" or "I":
            print("9")
        if c in "j" or "J":
            print("10")
        if c in "k" or "K":
            print("11")
        if c in "l" or "L":
            print("12")
        if c in "m" or "M":
            print("13")
        if c in "n" or "N":
            print("14")
        if c in "o" or "O":
            print("15")
        if c in "p" or "P":
            print("16")
        if c in "q" or "Q":
            print("17")
        if c in "r" or "R":
            print("18")
        if c in "s" or "S":
            print("19")
        if c in "t" or "T":
            print("20")
        if c in "u" or "U":
            print("21")
        if c in "v" or "V":
            print("22")
        if c in "w" or "W":
            print("23")
        if c in "x" or "X":
            print("24")
        if c in "y" or "Y":
            print("25")
        if c in "z" or "Z":
            print("26")
```

If i do something like this i think it's bad and also with the Output.Please help me to minimalize the 'if' statement

Comment: By the way, `c in "x" or "X"` does not do what you expect it to do. It's equivalent to `(c in 'x') or 'X'` which is always a "truthy" value.

Comment: Note that `if c in "a" or "A":` groups as `if (c in "a") or "A":` and is always `True`.  To achieve the test you want, it would need to be `if c in ("a", "A"):`, or `if c.lower() == "a":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a translation dict:

```
xlate = {
    'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, ...
}

print(xlate[c.lower()])
```

If your translation is simply the alphabet, in order, use `ord` and basic arithmetic to directly compute the value you need.

Answer (score 2):

for this specific use case

```
print(ord(c.lower()[0]) - ord('a') + 1)
#convert character to ascii and subtract ascii of a ... then add 1
```

more generally ... use a dict

```
conversions = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase,range(1,27)))
print(conversions.get(c.lower()[0],'???'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally when you have a lot of ifs going over many specific scenarios, try understanding what logic is bringing you to each of the specific ifs. 
If you can generalize that logic, you'll be able to make your code much shorter :)

So in this scenario, by going over the specific scenarios, it looks like you're mapping letters (ignoring their case) to numbers in an ascending order.
So we can say:

```
for c in input():
    lowercase_letter = c.lower() # We don't care about casing
    print(ord(lowercase_letter) - ord('a') + 1) # ord is the numeric value of a letter- a is 97, b is 98 and so on. We can subtract the value of a to start at 1 and go from there
```

Comment: What if i don't use numberic? like a = À b = B c =  ç and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Just use these two functions

```
for c in input().lower():
    print(ord(c))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help i appreciate it